# undefined function mysqli_connect() through url

Tags: php, mysqli, server

I used to use Centos 7.2.1511, Apache 2.4.6, MariaDB5.5.52 and php 5.4 as my web server. But recently I updated php to 7.1.7. So I can't use functions like "mysql_connect()" anymore.

After I replaced them with "mysqli_connect()", I met a problem. I can execute the php file **directly in the server** successfully. But when I do it **through the url**, I get the error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect().

Why did that happen? Is there something wrong with my Apache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the command line version of php is not necessarily the same as the one used through apache.

(could still be on php 5.4)

But even if it was updated as well:  you could have an other php.ini in both situation.
`<?php phpinfo(); ?>`
should reveal what php.ini is found and loaded

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps: https://serverfault.com/questions/428800/how-do-i-tell-apache-which-php-to-use .

In my case the 'libphp5.so' file is located in

/etc/httpd/modules -> ../../usr/lib64/httpd/modules

You might have to copy the new files to this location or create symbolic links to the new files.